# In C++ non-member function and global function are the same?

Tags: c++, function, global

I heard of "global function" as a synonym of "non-member function" in a Hungarian university (BME) at Budapest.

For example here: https://prog2.cppftw.org/ea02/ (of course this is in Hungarian, but there is google translate, you know).

Is this a common synonym or just used here?

Comment: _"...Function declarations may appear in any scope. A function declaration at class scope introduces a class member function ..."_ have a read of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: `namespace space {
void function(){
    std::cout <<"function";
}
}` this is not a global function and not a member function

Comment: Technically, probably not, a non-member function can be in a namespace and therefore not global. Practically, often yes. Personally, I never cared how to call them, I don't think it matters unless you're writing a book or teaching students, and I don't do either of these.

Comment: The terminology I've heard for them is *free functions*.

Comment: It seems strange to rely on something in Hungarian as an example of a synonym in English.

Comment: It appears somehow sloppy to me to provide a link and just recommend google translate instead of citing the relevant text into your question. (You even could provide the Hungarian and English text side by side.) I have some doubts whether the google translate is able to catch the subtle details of Hungarian IT terms (or especially C++ terms).